# Fill out remaining height of dynamic div

Tags: css

How can I get the bottom box of the lefthand side to fill out the rest of the height of the div so the border goes down to the bottom of the box?

Right now the line stops where the content of the left box stops

HTML

```
<div id="container">
        <div id="leftcolumn">
            <div id="fixedbox">
                Fixed size
            </div>
            <div id="restbox"><p>Fill out box</P></div>
        </div>
        <div id="rightcolumn">

            <p>Dynamic content</p>

        </div>
        <br style="clear:both;" />
    </div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    background-color:#ccc;
}
#container {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:80%;
    background-color: #fff;

}
#leftcolumn {
    width:29%;
        float:left;
        border-right:1px solid #000;

    }

    #rightcolumn {
width:68%;
        float:left;
        margin-left: 2%
    }

    #fixedbox {

        width:100%;
        height:200px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    }

    #restbox {
        width:100%;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/P6YQc/2/

Comment: Use `display: table-cell;` is the solution

Comment: In the future, please search before asking, there are countless questions about this topic.

Comment: I have searched a lot but many of the solutions is not with dynamic content, but a matter of filling out the rest of the browserheight. I have tried with table-cell but can't get i to work. I will close down the question and give it another try. Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason why you don't have a left border on #rightcolumn instead of a right border on #leftcolumn ?

http://jsfiddle.net/P6YQc/7/

eg:

```
#leftcolumn {
    width:29%;
    float:left;
}

#rightcolumn {
    width:68%;
    float:left;
    border-left:1px solid #000;
    padding-left:10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Yes. It is because the in the website where it is to be used there are an extra column between where the content is also not as long as the dynamic content, so this is just an example.